# Keyboard is always showing in ios

Tags: ios, keyboard

Just now started to learn IOS.

In my sample app,

While I'm typing keyboard shows in ios simulator. But After finish typing I want to click a button "Click me".

But I cannot type button, Since the button is hidden in the keyboard. I don't Know how to hide the keyboard. I clicked on the return button in the keyboard, but it doesn't hide.

How Can I click the button "Click me" ? What is the default functionality in IOS ?

Comment: follow the link and set delegate first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. :-) I've added your code in sample.m file. But there is no action performed. What should i do ?

Comment: [textfield resignFirstResponder];     change "textField" with ur text field name

Comment: did u added this, yourtextfield.delegate=self;

Comment: Thank you so much :-). I 've to wait for 6 minutes to mark it as answer :-(

Comment: Then, u can validate my answer.

Comment: I gave upvote for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface MyController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
   UITextField *yourTextField;


}
```

.m file

```
yourTextField.delegate=self;

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
  return YES;
}
```